# Selecting polygons based on geometry (specifically right angles) using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have some land registry data and I would like to know if there is a way of selecting all the polygons that contain a right angle.

I'm using (basic license) Arcgis 10.5.1.

Here's and image of part of the data with the an example polygon I would like to capture

[image: Here's and image of part of the data with the an example polygon I would like to capture]

Comment: If you need the same question answered for QGIS then please ask it as a separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [(Calculate Polygon Main Angle)](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/cartography-toolbox/calculate-polygon-main-angle.htm)

First you need to add numerical field to your shapefile (call it e.g angle)

Then open the (Calculate Polygon Main Angle) and define you dataset, and the angle field.

[image]

Then,  select by attribute, select when Angle = 0,90,-90

```
"Angle" = 0 OR "Angle" = 90 OR "Angle" =-90
```

[image]

And the result:

[image]

PS: this method in not totally accurate because the computed angle (The dominant angle of a polygon is the angle of longest collection of segments that have similar orientation. This angle will be stored in the specified field in decimal degrees from true north)[[ARCGIS]](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/cartography-toolbox/calculate-polygon-main-angle.htm).